# How to change the before and after labels in the Twenty Twenty plugin?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

If you are not familiar with the [TwentyTwenty](http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty) plugin, it is a visual difference tool that allows you to highlight the differences between two images.

I am using their plugin on wordpress because I require the function of sliding between two images. However, when you hover over the image it says before and after by default.

[Before and after labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiaxh.png)

Basically what I want to do is to change the before and after labels so they can say something else. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: This question is better asked on [wordpress.se].

Comment: Oh good call. I think I've figured it out anyways. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain twentytwenty.css, change your html, providing a unique ID for each div container:

```
<div id="set_1" class="twentytwenty-container">    
    <img src="img/1_1.jpg" />
    <img src="img/1_2.jpg" />
</div>
```

...and provide css to provide unique text for set_1:

```
#set_1 .twentytwenty-before-label:before {
    content: "new before" }
#set_1 .twentytwenty-after-label:before {
    content: "new after" }
```

This enables you to maintain the original *before* and *after* text, when needed, and provide unique labelling when you implement more than one image comparison.

Comment: Why in the world some developer should put this labels in the CSS files? Then how to translate these?

Comment: Really OMFG... I have solved this by adding data-title on images with PHP , with JS I have set fetched them and created new CSS styles which I had to append into the head because of course you can't change pseudoelements with JavaScript... brilliant

Answer (score 1):

Set labels via plugin options:

```
$(".twentytwenty-container").twentytwenty({
    before_label: 'Before',
    after_label: 'After'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change these parameters by modifying the following lines in the file twentytwenty.css:

```
.twentytwenty-before-label {
  opacity: 0; }
  .twentytwenty-before-label:before {
    content: "**Before**"; }

.twentytwenty-after-label {
  opacity: 0; }
  .twentytwenty-after-label:before {
    content: "**After**"; }
```

this part of css appears from line 102